go -ethereum abi: cannot marshal in to go type: length insufficient 640 require 8225"
Im trying to decode a struct which basically is a tuple where i have this byte of data and passing the byte of data it will be able to be decoded into a struct in Go. My goal here is trying to create a function similar from solidity to go. But when i try to decode it somehow it shows that the abi: cannot marshal in to go type: length insufficient 640 require 8225" Here is what my code looks like
type SignatureWrappers struct {
    OwnerIndex    *big.Int `abi: "ownerIndex"`
    SignatureData []byte   `abi: "signatureData"`
}


func main() {
    const signatrueWrap = `[{"name":"tuple","type":"function","outputs":[
            {"name":"ownerIndex","type":"uint256"},
            {"name":"signatureData","type":"bytes"}
        ]}]`

    // The hex string to decode
    hexString := "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000170000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001bbd5971f36187ed90f48c9718da85cdc46e9b046d6cfb11b09a8cc03441cde0f007cea1c001c007f903e10f802463815a2ff559c8e9b85de91df8c49df9c3125000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002549960de5880e8c687434170f6476605b8fe4aeb9a28632c7995cf3ba831d97630500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008a7b2274797065223a22776562617574686e2e676574222c226368616c6c656e6765223a226b4e6f744f506d4a774f774e755156374d4b33546e424e786e346f4971344846745f5532445f7461514e67222c226f726967696e223a2268747470733a2f2f7369676e2e636f696e626173652e636f6d222c2263726f73734f726967696e223a66616c73657d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

    // Decode the hex string to bytes
    data := common.Hex2Bytes(hexString)
    if data == nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to decode hex string")
    }

    // Define the ABI
    parsedABI, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(signatrueWrap))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to parse ABI: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Parsed ABI: %+v\n", parsedABI)

    result, err := parsedABI.Unpack("tuple", data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to unpack data: %v", err)
    }

    sig := SignatureWrappers{
        OwnerIndex:    *abi.ConvertType(result[0], new(*big.Int)).(**big.Int),
        SignatureData: result[1].([]byte),
    }

    // Print the result
    sigJSON, err := json.MarshalIndent(sig, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to marshal SigJSON: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(sigJSON))
}

